# Python handling formula differently than expected

Tags: python, python-3.6

I'm creating a dive table for private use and I'm running into an error for calculating EAD

```
def calculate_ead(self):
    nitrogen = 100 - self.mix
    EAD = (self.depth + 10) * nitrogen / 0.79 - 10
    self.depth = int(EAD)
```

This calculation gives off an insanely high number (around thousands). I got the formula off of [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalent_air_depth) site and in the calculations in feet section. The calculation when the mix is above 21 should give off a lower number than the depth.

My Initializing of depth and other things:

```
def __init__(self, d=35, t=30, m=21, p=1.6):
        self.depth = int(d)  # Depth
        self.time = int(t)  # Time
        self.mix = int(m)  # Mix (Oxygen integer)
        self.max_po2 = float(p)
```

Mix in this case in the percentage of oxygen so when a hundred is subtracted by it it should give the fraction of nitrogen for this formula EAD = (Depth + 10) × Fraction of N2 / 0.79 − 10

Tell me what I'm doing wrong?
Sample test from interactive shell:

```
depth = 90
mix = 36
nitrogen = 100 - mix
EAD = (depth + 10) * nitrogen / 0.79 + 10
EAD
8111.26582278481
```

Expected Output:

```
>>>depth = 90
>>>mix = 36
>>>nitrogen = 100 - mix
>>>EAD = (depth + 10) * nitrogen / 0.79 + 10
>>>EAD
67
```

Formats for the numbers:
self.depth is a natural number (25, 30,35)
self.mix is a natural number (30, 45, 60)

Comment: You say the "calculations in feet" section, but your constants are from "calculations in meters". Are you sure `self.mix` is in percents (ie 20) and not in fractions (ie 0.20)?

Comment: Why would you expect 67? You're basically multiplying 100 (depth + 10) with 81 (nitrogen / 0.79) and then adding 10, so getting 8111 seems pretty correct to me? :-)

By the way, in your code you do - 10 at the end, but in your examples you end with + 10, so there seems to be more confusion even?

Comment: @hughbothwell is right, lines should be mix = 0.36; nitrogen = 1 - mix

Comment: You switched also + 10 when it's - 10. "71" is the approximate final result with that numbers

Comment: My self.mix is an integer of a natural number (20, 30, 45) and not 0.20 0.30 .045

Comment: Okay seems like I'm bad at typing things. I've mixed up the metric formula and the imperial one and typed a natural number instead of decimal so... my bad..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the link you provided, 
The equivalent air depth can be calculated for depths in feet as follows:

> EAD = (Depth + 33) × Fraction of N2 / 0.79 − 33

Applying that your numbers,

```
depth = 90
mix = 36
nitrogen = float(100 - mix) /100 #Fraction of N2
EAD = (depth + 33) * nitrogen / 0.79 - 33
print EAD
```

Will give correct result in feets.

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
66.6455696203
>>>
```

Comment: Okay seems like I'm bad at typing things. I've mixed up the metric formula and the imperial one and typed a natural number instead of decimal so... my bad..

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to use fraction(%) of N2, try the following code.

```
def calculate_ead(self):
    nitrogen = (100 - self.mix)/100
    EAD = (self.depth + 10) * nitrogen / 0.79 - 10
    self.depth = int(EAD)
```